# CakeDC/Users - Tipos de usuários

Tags: cakephp, plugin, cakephp-3

Implantei o plugin de autenticação CakeDC/Users e quero adicionar outros tipos de usuários ao meu sistema.

Atualmente tenho somente as duas permissões padrão: superuser e user.

Estou fazendo o controle de permissões através do arquivo permissions.php.

Estou também sobreescrevendo os arquivos de layout, tentei inicialmente forçar o campo role no formulário, mas ele força o tipo de usuário diretamente no controller do plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o steinkel passou nesse issue: https://github.com/CakeDC/users/issues/513

Basta adicionar essa linha após o pathEntity em /vendor/cakedc/user/src/Controller/Traits/SimpleCrudTrait.php

```
$entity->role = $this->request->data('role');
```

E então **configurar seu formulário para passar o campo role**. No meu caso, passei essa informação através de um select.